Rough conversion in SQL for decimal degrees to square meters/meters
I'm dealing with a database (Teradata) that doesn't have any support for anything other than decimals/decimal degrees. As a result I can't use any of:

ST_Area (can't get area in square meters)
ST_Buffer (can't specify a distance in meters)
ST_Distance (can't get a distance in linear meters)
ST_Length (can't get a length in linear meters)

So is there a way to calculate these values in meters within the SQL itself. For example:
SELECT DECIMAL_TO_SQ_METERS(geo_column.ST_Area()))
FROM my_table


It's a partial differential equation only resolvable by numerical methods (looping with lots of trigonometric functions and an epsilon value), This is not exactly a SQL strength.

Doesn't sound promising, I guess that's why it's supposed to be supported server side.

Clients can compute it, but you want a compiled binary doing the work, and for most purposes you want an ST_DWithin to leverage the R-tree index.

If you have a geodetically-aware client library, you could use a worst case conversion of 60nm/degree, and if you want to get fancy, scale the X component by cos(lat_radians). Then use the client to filter results in actual meters.

Look at ST_Transform again. According to the docs you can pass in a WKT string so you may not need to rely on the teradata SRIDs available in your DB. You could then use a UTM or Albers CRS.

Doesn't that have to be a coordinate system known to Teradata?

ST_Transform doesn't really work either. I don't think anyone is even maintaining any of this. The lack of information is quite something.
